# Linking jsp and java

Tags: java, database, web-services, jsp

I am trying to create a login page using jsp. How do I link these two so that I can retrieve the information filled in a jsp page to my respective java class? I am using IBM's Rational Application Developer(RAD) & DB2 as database.

Comment: can you post your code snippet?? What have you tried till now??

Comment: By java page, r u referring to Servlet ?

Comment: this link will help you... http://www.roseindia.net/jsp/user-search.shtml

Comment: @Fahim: roseindia.net is the **worst** resource when it comes to "best practices" shown in the code examples. It's so full of bad practices.

Comment: @BalusC : I do know that... but for beginner I feel it is good... (For experts, yes Its WORST)...

Answer (score 1):

You should map the form element in your JSP  with servlet. Your form in JSP probably uses a method GET/POST. It is forwarded to a URL pattern. This URL pattern is matched with a servlet class name in the application. You can reach such kind of mappings / matchings in your application's `web.xml` file or something similar.

The answer to your question *"How to link java page and jsp page?"*, check out this mapping configuration carefully.

Answer (score 1):

You need a [servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info). Assuming that you've a `/WEB-INF/login.jsp` which contains this form,

```
<form action="login" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username" />
    <input type="secret" name="password" />
    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

then you can write the servlet as follows,

```
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/login.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");

        // Do your Java job here.

        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/login.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

}
```

If you register the servlet in `web.xml` as follows

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>loginServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.controller.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>loginServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Then you can open it by

> http://localhost:8080/contextname/login

This way the servlet's `doGet()` will be called and display the JSP. When you submit the form, the servlet's `doPost()` will be called where you can do business actions based on the submitted values.

#### See also:

- [Our servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) - contains Hello World examples and good tutorial links

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve all the JSP page data in java simply using getParameter(param_name)..For that you have to call java class and you can call java class either through scriplets or through action method of HTML form